# regex to validate user id

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a client side validation of userid using javascript. Sample inputs are

1. `!abc`
2. `abc-def , abc`
3. `abc , abc-def`
4. `abc`
5. `abc-def_hjk`

I have made a regex `([\w]*[-]?[\w]+[\s]?[,]?[\s]?)+`. It matches `2,3,4,5` as needed but also matches input `1`, which is invalid.
Please let me know what is wrong in this regex.

Comment: Did you start your regex with `^` sign and end with `$` ? Otherwise it will not match whole string.

Comment: Thank you.It worked. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `\w`. try using `a-zA-Z_` instead. this makes sure that only alphabet is used

Answer (score 0):

\d, \w and \s   Shorthand character classes matching digits, word characters (letters, digits, and underscores), and whitespace (spaces, tabs, and line breaks). Can be used inside and outside character classes. 
\D, \W and \S   Negated versions of the above. Should be used only outside character classes. (Can be used inside, but that is confusing.)